# VBScript (classic ASP) Performance - Store string length in a temporary variable in a loop

Tags: performance, asp-classic, vbscript, string-length

I would like to know if the performance is better in case I am storing the string length
in a temporary variable when I am using a loop of at list 10,000 loops instead of calculating it in every loop?

Code example calculating the string length:

```
'--
Dim I
Dim str : str = "Lets say this string length is around 50,000"
'--
For I=0 To 100000
    Response.Write Len(str) & "<br>"
Next
```

Code example using a temporary variable:

```
'--
Dim I
Dim str : str = "Lets say this string length is around 50,000"
Dim temp : temp = Len(str)
'--
For I=0 To 100000
    Response.Write temp & "<br>"
Next
```

What do you think is better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idea: Why don't you just measure it?

```
Dim start: start = Timer
...<code here>...
Response.Write FormatNumber(Timer - start, 8)
```

To measure is to know. Having said that: You might want to read the story about [Shlemiel the Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Eventually the Response.write will probably be the most expensive operation; if you really want to measure the "cost" of Len() vs. a temp variable (even though both methods output the same amount of data) you should probably do something like this:

```
Dim I, J, X
Dim start

Dim str : str = String(50000, "-")
Dim tmp : tmp = Len(str)

Response.Write "Temp var:<br>"
For J = 0 to 10
    start = Timer
    X = 0
    For I=0 To 100000
        x = x + tmp
    Next
    Response.write FormatNumber(Timer - start,8) & "<br>"
Next

Response.Write "Len:<br>"
For J = 0 to 10
    start = Timer
    X = 0
    For I=0 To 100000
        x = x + Len(str)
    Next
    Response.write FormatNumber(Timer - start,8) & "<br>"
Next
```

In my case, the output is:

```
Temp var:
0,03125000
0,03125000
0,04687500
0,03125000
0,03515625
0,02734375
0,03125000
0,03125000
0,03515625
0,02734375
0,03125000
Len:
0,04687500
0,04687500
0,03125000
0,04687500
0,04687500
0,04687500
0,05078125
0,02734375
0,04687500
0,05078125
0,04687500
```

As you can see, using Len() every iteration is measureably slower (even though it isn't that much, about 35%). Using a temp-variable will be a good idea, but you could've guessed that without this knowledge or measuring at all, didn't you?

I am unsure about VBScript but many languages (and their compilers/JIT'ers) do optimize this stuff at compile/JIT-time on their own. The compiler/runtime/JIT usually "notices" these kinds of patterns and will introduce a "temp variable" automatically.

But then: why would you be doing tens-of-thousands of iterations on such a large chunk of data in (classic) ASP at all? Do you really have to output this much data? Can't the processing be done (more) by the backend or something? Are you doing actually 10.000 iterations on 50Kb strings? Or is this just a theoretical discussion? If you're doing one, or a handful, iterations, on "simple, short strings" I wouldn't bother with an extra variable at all. This introduces other issues; for example having to keep the variable "in sync" should the `str` variable change etc. Also readability (and "understandability) would be improved just using `Len(foo)` where you need the length. If you do introduce a variable, which is justified and sometimes an optimization worth the "hassle", I would at least make sure it is named correctly (not `tmp` but `foolength` for example).

Comment: @Robill +1 because all topics the OT should reflect upon are mentioned. Most important, in my opinion, is whether the string may change. If not, using a variable for the length is not optimization but standard procedure; if yes, the `len(str)` *can't* be done before the loop - regardless of the benchmark's result.

Comment: Hi,
First I like to thank you for just perfect answer.
I am using a variable and I try to test it using the CPU monitor but as I see now it is not a good way to test it, the timer idea is just excellent and I will do it next time that I need to test something.
The answer to the rest of your questions is that this is only a testing in a big project in a very big CMS system that already use ASP and I must use this language and also using at list this amount of loops on this at list the same amount of data.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you just follow the simple rule "Never do in a loop what you can do before it" you don't have to waste time on benchmarks.

(It's bitter to have to read such a question, and I want to batter a programmer who does not know on which side the toast is buttered.)

Comment: Then also follow the rule: Premature optimization is the root of all evil :P Seriously though: ofcourse you are correct; I just have the feeling `Roy Shoa` has trouble asking the actual question. I have this gut-feel there's more to it than this (over?)simplified example. That's why my answer suggests measuring ("poor mans profiling") and has a little bit more explanation.

Comment: Hi Ekkehard.Horner, I am not really agree with you on this one. Sometimes you also need your code to be understandably and in a case that you have a loop from 0 to 10 and you need to made length on five different strings you will not define five variables for every string length because the performance will be the same and you code looks like a, well I do not like to say how it will look :). One more thing is that it is really depend on the language that you are working with. Any way this is really a pic of code from a big project as Roblll say so he really understand me. Thanks for the Tip!